# Useless test failure messages for Jasmine in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: typescript, jasmine, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to figure out how to use Visual Studio 2019 for unit testing Jasmine tests written in TypeScript.

The standard *TypeScript Jasmine UnitTest file* template generates this file:

```
describe('Test Suite 1', () => {
    it('Test 1', () => {

        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });

    it('Test 2', () => {

        fail("this is expected to fail.")
    });
});
```

When I run it, I have, as expected, 1 succeeding and 1 failing test. When I click on the failing test (*Test 2*), I get this:

```
 Test 2
   Source: MazeGameTests.ts line 2
   Duration: 4 ms

   Open additional output for this result
```

This already seems wrong to me, because it reports that the failure happens on **line 2**. That's also where Visual Studio takes me when I click on the file name. *Test 2*, however, starts on line 7.

It gets worse, though. When I click on *Open additional output for this result*, I get this:

```
Test Name:  Test 2
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StandardOutput:  
Using Jasmine settings:  {}
Randomized with seed 00316
Started
F
```

Notice the last line: **F**.

It's not that I clipped the text. That's what it looks like.

This means that **assertion messages are not shown**.

That makes the test runner basically useless, since I can't see where and why tests fail. Is this a known problem? Can it be addressed?

Comment: Regarding line number error maybe you have to enable typescript source map generation?

Comment: @DavideIcardi That sounds like a great suggestion. How do I do that?

Comment: FWIW I even tried with plain JavaScript and got the same results: https://twitter.com/nikosbaxevanis/status/1213110308270727169